# It seems that wget is ignoring my --wait and --random-wait parameters

Tags: web-scraping, wget

```
c:\Users\mds\Downloads\foo\wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" --recursive --level=0 --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent --restrict-file-names=windows  --wait=80 --random-wait --output-file="logfile.txt" https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual
```

I'm trying to be nice and specify an eighty second wait time + the randomness factor supplied by --random-wait.

But when I look at the logfile, it seems that wget is hammering out requests as fast as it is able. There are scores of requests sent out immediately at 22:01:17+ as example.  All the docs I can find say that the parameter value is in seconds, not milliseconds.

Downloaded a binary for windows referenced from the gnu site (not sourceforge)

> C:\Users\mds\Downloads\foo>wget --version GNU Wget 1.17.1 built on
>   mingw32.
>
> +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +metalink -nls +ntlm
>   +opie -psl +ssl/openssl
>
> Wgetrc:
>       /win32dev/misc/wget/out64/etc/wgetrc (system) Compile:
>       x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
>       -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/etc/wgetrc"
>       -DLOCALEDIR="/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/share/locale" -I. -I../lib
>       -I../lib -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/include
>       -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/include
>       -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/include
>       -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/include -DHAVE_LIBSSL -DNDEBUG Link:
>       x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/include
>       -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/include -DHAVE_LIBSSL -DNDEBUG
>       -L/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/lib -L/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/lib
>       /win32dev/misc/wget/out64/lib/libiconv.a
>       -L/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/lib -lmetalink
>       -L/win32dev/misc/wget/out64/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lws2_32 -lole32
>       -lidn ftp-opie.o mswindows.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a
>
> Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU
>   GPL version 3 or later http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html. This is
>   free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO
>   WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic . Please send
>   bug reports and questions to .

This is the logfile the command generated showing the high-frequency requests:

> --2016-04-20 22:01:17--  https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual Resolving www.gnu.org (www.gnu.org)... 208.118.235.148 Connecting to
>   www.gnu.org (www.gnu.org)|208.118.235.148|:443... connected. HTTP
>   request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently Location:
>   https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/ [following]
>   --2016-04-20 22:01:19--  https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/ Reusing existing connection to www.gnu.org:443. HTTP request sent,
>   awaiting response... 200 OK Length: unspecified [text/html] Saving to:
>   'www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual.html'
>
> ```
>  0K .........                                              1.01M=0.009s
> ```
>
> 2016-04-20 22:01:20 (1.01 MB/s) -
>   'www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual.html' saved [9313]
>
> Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
>   --2016-04-20 22:01:20--  https://www.gnu.org/robots.txt Reusing existing connection to www.gnu.org:443. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 200 OK Length: 190 [text/plain] Saving to:
>   'www.gnu.org/robots.txt'
>
> ```
>  0K                                                       100%  873K=0s
> ```
>
> 2016-04-20 22:01:21 (873 KB/s) - 'www.gnu.org/robots.txt' saved
>   [190/190]
>
> --2016-04-20 22:01:21--  https://www.gnu.org/combo.css Reusing existing connection to www.gnu.org:443. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 200 OK Length: 6746 (6.6K) [text/css] Saving to:
>   'www.gnu.org/combo.css'
>
> ```
>  0K ......                                                100% 3.09M=0.002s
> ```
>
> 2016-04-20 22:01:21 (3.09 MB/s) - 'www.gnu.org/combo.css' saved
>   [6746/6746]
>
> --2016-04-20 22:01:21--  https://www.gnu.org/mini.css Reusing existing connection to www.gnu.org:443. HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
>   200 OK Length: 1821 (1.8K) [text/css] Saving to:
>   'www.gnu.org/mini.css'
>
> ```
>  0K .                                                     100% 13.0M=0s
> ```
>
> 2016-04-20 22:01:21 (13.0 MB/s) - 'www.gnu.org/mini.css' saved
>   [1821/1821]
>
> --2016-04-20 22:01:21--  https://www.gnu.org/layout.min.css Reusing existing connection to www.gnu.org:443. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 200 OK Length: 14522 (14K) [text/css] Saving to:
>   'www.gnu.org/layout.m

===================

UPDATE:

I tried using an older 1.1.16 version of wget -- same behavior.

I ran it with debug mode, and it claims to be using 15s wait.  But when I look at the logfile, it doesn't seem to be delaying requests.

[image]

[fragment of the logfile from the --debug operation. I think it shows no 5s wait-delay between requests](http://pastebin.com/y7Fti4X1)

Moreover, a friend of mine ran the same command on his osx box, and it clearly paused 5s between requests.

Comment: I've tried many combinations of --wait and --random-wait and -no-http-keep-alive, yet still have the same behavior.

Comment: I've also tried older version 1.1.16, and still demonstrates same problem.

Comment: same here, have you solved this?, I just used the --wait flag

Comment: @briankip  Sorry, I don't clearly recall. But I THINK I switched from using a downloaded win7 binary and switched to using the WGET that is included in cygwin?  I'm reading through old notes and that's what it looks like.